# Jquery form submit not working, instead get js warning 'body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode' in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my js file:

```
function PS_SL_HandleEvent()
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit(function(e) {
            if(acceptCGV())
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($('#send_order_form input[type="radio"]:checked').val() == "")
                {
                    resetAjaxQueries();
                    delSelection(1);
                }
                else
                {

                    var carrierClass = $('input:radio[name="order_choose"]:checked').attr('class');
                    carrierClass = carrierClass.replace("carrier_","");
                    var radio_selector = '.delivery_options_address input[value="' + carrierClass + ',"], #carrierTable input[value="' + carrierClass + '"]';
                    $(radio_selector).attr('checked','checked');

                    resetAjaxQueries();
                    saveSelection(1);
                }
            }
            else
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
}

function saveSelection(is_submit)
{
    $('#sendwithorder_errors').slideUp();
    $('#sendwithorder_errors_list').children().remove();
    //displayWaitingAjax('block', SL_RedirectTS);
    //$('.SE_SubmitRefreshCard').fadeOut('fast');

    var query = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url: baseDir + 'modules/sendwithorder/ajax.php' + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        data: 'method=saveSelection&' + 'order_choose=' + $('#send_order_form input[name=order_choose]:checked').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.length)
            {
                for (error in json)
                    $('#sendwithorder_errors_list').append('<li>'+json[error]+'</li>');
                $('#sendwithorder_errors').slideDown();
                displayWaitingAjax('none', '');
            }
            else
            {                
                displayWaitingAjax('none', '');
                if(is_submit==1)
                {
                    $('#form').submit();
                    alert("sam");
                }
                //$('#show_carrier, .SE_SubmitRefreshCard span').show();
                //$('.SE_SubmitRefreshCard').fadeIn('fast');
                //$('#SE_AjaxSuccess').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                //location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });
    ajaxQueries.push(query);
    return false;
}
```

Even "sam" is alerted but the form does not submit. Instead, I get the following warning on submit:

```
body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode.
```

Even though there is a javascript warning, but this should not hinder form submit.

Comment: What do you mean by "form does not submit". Are you seeing an HTTP error status in your console? Have you verified that the form is being sent to the server? Have you checked the contents of the POST request to confirm that they're valid?

Comment: Yup, during post, I save some info in a table in mysql database, and it is saved.

Comment: So it sounds like it's working. What's not working?

Comment: Form is not getting submitted ($("#form").submit(); not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form cannot be submitted since you call `e.preventDefault();` at every submit.

Try reorganizing the logic in submit() to either `preventDefault()` and go through your checks, or do nothing and let the form be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and the code worked:

```
var js_submit = false;

function PS_SL_HandleEvent() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit(function (e) {
            if (js_submit == false) {
                if (acceptCGV()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($('#send_order_form input[type="radio"]:checked').val() == "") {
                        resetAjaxQueries();
                        delSelection(1);
                    } else {

                        var carrierClass = $('input:radio[name="order_choose"]:checked').attr('class');
                        carrierClass = carrierClass.replace("carrier_", "");
                        var radio_selector = '.delivery_options_address input[value="' + carrierClass + ',"], #carrierTable input[value="' + carrierClass + '"]';
                        $(radio_selector).attr('checked', 'checked');

                        resetAjaxQueries();
                        saveSelection(1);
                    }
                } else
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
}

function saveSelection(is_submit) {
    $('#sendwithorder_errors').slideUp();
    $('#sendwithorder_errors_list').children().remove();
    //displayWaitingAjax('block', SL_RedirectTS);
    //$('.SE_SubmitRefreshCard').fadeOut('fast');

    var query = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        url: baseDir + 'modules/sendwithorder/ajax.php' + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        data: 'method=saveSelection&' + 'order_choose=' + $('#send_order_form input[name=order_choose]:checked').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.length) {
                for (error in json)
                    $('#sendwithorder_errors_list').append('<li>' + json[error] + '</li>');
                $('#sendwithorder_errors').slideDown();
                displayWaitingAjax('none', '');
            } else {
                displayWaitingAjax('none', '');
                if (is_submit == 1) {
                    js_submit = true;
                    $('#form').submit();
                }
                //$('#show_carrier, .SE_SubmitRefreshCard span').show();
                //$('.SE_SubmitRefreshCard').fadeIn('fast');
                //$('#SE_AjaxSuccess').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                //location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });
    ajaxQueries.push(query);
    return false;
}
```